# Create a user defined number of loops for quiz in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to have a user defined amount of time the questions are asked and keep track of the attempts

```
def main(): 
    print("Thank you for taking the Quiz")

    score= 0
    question1 = input("How many donuts are in a dozen? ")
    if question1 == "12":
        print("Correct")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

    question2 = input("How many mb are in a gb? ")
    if question2 == "1024":
        print("Correct")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

    question3 = input("How many pokemon are in gen 1? ")
    if question3 == "151":
        print("Correct")
        score = score +1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")




    print("The final score is: " + str(score), "out of 3")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
    def main(): 
        print("Thank you for taking the Quiz")

        times = input("How many time you'll play? ")

        for i in range(int(times))
            print("The final score is: " + str(question), "out of 3")

def question():
        score= 0
        question1 = input("How many donuts are in a dozen? ")
        if question1 == "12":
            print("Correct")
            score = score +1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

        question2 = input("How many mb are in a gb? ")
        if question2 == "1024":
            print("Correct")
            score = score +1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

        question3 = input("How many pokemon are in gen 1? ")
        if question3 == "151":
            print("Correct")
            score = score +1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

        return score

    main()
```

Comment: Im getting this when i tried that
Thank you for taking the Quiz
How many time you'll play? 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hunte/OneDrive/Intro to coding/quiz 3.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Hunte/OneDrive/Intro to coding/quiz 3.py", line 6, in main
    for i in range(times):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>

Comment: You need to convert input to `int` if you want to put in `range()`.

Comment: how would i got about that